# Boostrap push / pull exceeding 12 cols

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, push, pull

I have columns that I want to reorder but don't know how.

Mobile order:

```
<col-xs-12 col-sm-4>
<col-xs-12>
<col-xs-12 col-sm-4>
<col-xs-12>
<col-xs-12 col-sm-4>
<col-xs-12>
```

Desktop it should be:

```
<col-xs-12 col-sm-4>
<col-xs-12 col-sm-4>
<col-xs-12 col-sm-4>
<col-xs-12>
<col-xs-12>
<col-xs-12>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

So you need to change one div at a time.

Let's consider this html code:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="one"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12" id="two"></div>
<div class="col-xs-12"></div>
```

We'll make the changes with this jquery code then :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if(screen.width>=768){
        $('#one').addClass('col-sm-4');
        if($('#two').hasClass('col-sm-4')){
            $('#two').removeClass('col-sm-4');
        }
    }else{
        $('#two').addClass('col-sm-4');
        if($('#one').hasClass('col-sm-4')){
            $('#one').removeClass('col-sm-4');
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try it out. Is this not possible with pull and push?

Comment: I think you can push some data to the DOM because it's considered as an array , but the pull function I'm not used to it , I even made a quick search for it, and I couldn't find it with JS or JQuery , are you using a library that has this function?

Comment: Sorry I mean pull and push in CSS --> bootstrap.